# Circle pagination buttons with text below them in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create bootstrap pagination with circled numbers, actually managed half of it by modifying the css like,

```
    .pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span{
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a, .pagination > li:first-child > span,.pagination > li:last-child > a, .pagination > li:last-child > span {
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

however there are two things I still could not figure out.
1. How can I add the line behind the circle items? They might be 3 or 4 items so an image would not work.
2.Anyone can point me a way how to add the text below the circles which will always align with the circle and push the other items so that there is a space between the items?

```
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">   
<li>
<a href="#">1<p class="pagination-text">Lorem Ipsum</p></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">2<p class="pagination-text">Dolor Sit Amet</p></a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Bootstrap circle pagination items with text]

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that line style with some `:pseudo selectors` and working you way from them.

So, starting from your markup:

- `float` the `li` items and give em some specified `width`, in px, percentage or whatever you see fit; also set a `text-align: center`;
- I created that circle using a `:before` class, centered it, and gave the parent `a` tag a `line height` of `50px`, the height of the circle, to make the text in the circle at about half its height
- set the `p` tag `line height` to `1` to pull it back up, or you can better position it with some margins/paddings etc.
- for the lines behind the circle: my best bet was to use both `:after` & `:before` from the `li` item, since the `a` tag had already used a `:before` class
- both lines have a width of 50%, but not specified, I used `left` & `right` `props`. to give em a `width` and added some `margin-left/right` so that it would not show behind the circle(since its transparent initially)
- for the `first li` item, the `:before` class `doesnt show`, and also for the `last li` item, the `:after class` `doesnt show`, since `they werent connecting` with either `left li items` or `right li items`
- position these line at about `top: 25px;`, `half` the `height` of the `circle`
- and thats about it

Check the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/en3a5mab/)** or see the code snippet bellow:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pagination > li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.pagination > li p {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1;
}
.pagination > li > a {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
/*positon the circle*/

.pagination > li > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/*positioning the line*/

.pagination > li:not(:last-of-type):after,
.pagination > li:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 25px;
  height: 1px;
}
.pagination > li:first-of-type:after {
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.pagination > li:not(:first-of-type):before {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.pagination > li:not(:first-of-type):after {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
/*hover stuff*/

.pagination > li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.pagination > li:hover a:before {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                1
                <p class="pagination-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                2
                <p class="pagination-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                3
                <p class="pagination-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! :) Also I had to change some bootstrap pre-defined classes because with those your code was showing rectangle buttons:) Thanks again. I hope this would be helpful for those needs buttons like this.

Comment: @cevizmx No problem-o, glad to help out!